# PHP Composite Design Pattern with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composite

Is there any example for [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) with Doctrine? I mean PHP source code using [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html) annotations.

I could find Decorator Pattern here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html but no luck about Composite Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Inheritance Mapping (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and just normal associations with the type you want (see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: I've read the documentation several times but I still don't get it, would you happen to have a code sample?